# Deploying Django projects with conda

Tags: django, deployment, conda, supervisord

Environment management in Python projects is critical and is commonly done with venv or virtualenv. However, I am interested in deploying a Django project with conda.

The basic setup looks like the one [here](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). Django is served using gunicorn which is controlled with supervisor.

That conda does not use folders as environments basically means that there is no isolated directory where the Django project could live (hope I got this right).

[This post](https://www.thoughtvector.io/blog/deployment-with-anaconda/) has a nice description of how to deploy a Python project with conda in general. For using this with supervisor I was thinking if activating a specific conda environment with installed dependencies in supervisor would suffice to create the needed results. I assume this supervisor config might look something like this:

```
[program:djangoapp]
command = .activate django-env; python gunicorn djangoapp.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:8000
directory = /path/to/djangoapp
...
```

The [supervisor docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) say that supervisor will search the supervisord’s environment $PATH for the executable, if it's provided without an absolute path. Does this mean that the absolute path of the conda environment needs to be used here?

Long story short: Is anyone using conda for this and is it even usable the way I like to do it and if yes: How?